# Subtract one group of values from all groups using group_by

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I subtract one group of values from all values using `group_by` in tibble.
Below is an example with expected results. I wish to subtract values of category "A" from all values

```
d <- tibble(categories = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)), 
            values = 1:9)

# expected outcome

d <- tibble(categories = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)), 
            values = c(0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the categories size are the same length, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
 d %>%
   mutate(values = values - d$values[d$categories == "A"])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  categories values
  <chr>       <int>
1 A               0
2 A               0
3 A               0
4 B               3
5 B               3
6 B               3
7 C               6
8 C               6
9 C               6
```

Comment: Maybe you can add `.by = categories` to consider the order if the data is not sorted.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Not clear about the sorting issue you mentioned.  My assumption (as I mentioned in the post) is if the lengths are the same, the subsetting the values for 'A' will do the recycling and subtract from the whole column

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(categories) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'categories',
              values_from = 'values') %>%
  mutate(across(-id, ~ . - A)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id,
               names_to = 'categories',
               values_to = 'values',
               cols_vary = 'slowest') %>%
  select(-id)
```

Alternatively:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(categories) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(values = values - values[categories == 'A' & id == id]) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  categories values
  <chr>       <int>
1 A               0
2 A               0
3 A               0
4 B               3
5 B               3
6 B               3
7 C               6
8 C               6
9 C               6
```